# Cannot assign material to an object or object face

Tags: materials

I'm a newbie, I'm using Blender 2.80 on Devuan Ceres Linux.
I'd like to create a sign object, which is super simple: an extruded cube makes up the pole section and another extruded cube is the sign portion. I try to assign material as I see it on various tutorials, but pressing the Assign button has no effect whatsoever.

1. I select a mesh face in Edit mode
2. On the material panel the right material is selected
3. I press Assign -> this should result in the material assigned to the face but nothing happens. Accordingly a render shows blacked out objects on the scene.

[Video of the issue](https://youtu.be/Wf2hdmPVPsA)

[The project file](https://github.com/MrCsabaToth/PoleSign/raw/master/sign1.blend)

Comment: You can't see the materials in solid view mode.

Comment: @FFeller can you give me a pointer to what to do? I was thinking maybe it's just my view mode, but then it should show up at least on my render. My render shows pitch black objects

Comment: @FFeller: not if it's a **texture**. With plain color everything is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to material preview mode

[image]

Comment: I found that although the option is on a different part of my screen. Now I try to figure out why my render is black, I assume my lightning is off somehow.

Comment: I needed to switch to the "Shading" tab to see what you show